# Using useSelector in React Function Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I declared a state in **baseReducer.ts**:

```
import {PayloadAction} from '~common/declarations/action';

const initialState = {
  test: 'baseReducer'
};

const BaseReducer = (state = initialState, action: PayloadAction<any>): any => {
  switch(action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default BaseReducer;
```

Then in my **orderReducer**:

```
import {PayloadAction} from '~common/declarations/action';

const initialState = {
  test: 'orderReducer'
};

const OrderReducer = (state = initialState, action: PayloadAction<any>): any => {
  switch(action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default OrderReducer ;
```

In my **rootReducer**:

```
const RootReducer: Reducer = combineReducers({
  BaseReducer,
  OrderReducer
});

export default RootReducer;
```

Now in my functional component **OrderPage.tsx**:

```
export default function OrderPage() {
  const stringText: string = useSelector(state => state.test)  // HERE
  return (
    <React.Fragment>Order Page</React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

**Here is my question**:

How do I define which state to take from? Ideally I want to specify the state from `OrderReducer`.

When using react Classes, I could do the following:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({orderReducer}) => {
  return {
    test: orderReducer.test
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

I tried the following (separately of course!), but it did not work:

```
const reducer: string = useSelector(state => state.baseReducer);
const reducer: string = useSelector(state => state.orderReducer);
```

How do I achieve the same in function components?

Comment: Function component - not functional component. Nothing functional about functions with state :)

Comment: I do not think baseReducer exists try const reducer: string = useSelector(state => state.OrderReducer); this is in  accordance to how you did combine reducers const RootReducer: Reducer = combineReducers({
  BaseReducer,
  OrderReducer
});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use correct selector function in `useSelector`:

```
const stringText = useSelector(state => state.OrderReducer.test)
```

Or, if you write like (without using [property name shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015)):

```
const RootReducer: Reducer = combineReducers({
  base: BaseReducer,
  order: OrderReducer
});
```

Then

```
const stringText = useSelector(state => state.order.test)
```

---

You can further avoid this error by defining [`RootState`](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#define-root-state-and-dispatch-types) type:

```
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
// ...
const stringText = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.OrderReducer.test)
```

#### Edit:

If you are getting error:

> OrderReducer does not exist on DefaultRootState.

Then you should define `RootState` type because `DefaultRootState` is just
`export interface DefaultRootState {}`.

Comment: I attempted the first solution, but intellij is claiming that OrderReducer does not exist on DefaultRootState. Is that different from the RootState?

Comment: where should i export the type RootState?

Comment: Did you mean state object? Store object was created using default method from redux in my App.tsx file